# Why is using tasks with HttpClient synchronously so much slower?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, xunit

So I was trying to do a quick performance test against a web api to see how it would handle multiple synchronous HTTP requests at once. I did this by spinning up 30 multiple tasks and have each of them send a http request with the `HttpClient`. To my surprise, it was extremely slow. I thought it was due to the lack of async/await or the web api was slow, but it turns out it's only when I'm using tasks and synchronous http calls (see `TestSynchronousWithParallelTasks()` below).

So I did a comparison between using without Tasks, async/await with tasks, and ParallelForEach by making some simple tests. All of these finished quickly around 10-20 milliseconds, but the original case which takes around 20 seconds!

`Class: HttpClientTest Passed (5)   19.2 sec         TestProject.HttpClientTest.TestAsyncWithParallelTasks Passed    12 ms        TestProject.HttpClientTest.TestIterativeAndSynchronous Passed   22 ms        TestProject.HttpClientTest.TestParallelForEach Passed   15 ms        TestProject.HttpClientTest.TestSynchronousWithParallelTasks Passed  19.1 sec         TestProject.HttpClientTest.TestSynchronousWithParallelThreads Passed    10 ms`

```
public class HttpClientTest
{
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;

    public HttpClientTest(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
        httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100 });
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestSynchronousWithParallelTasks()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var url = "https://localhost:44388/api/values";

        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            });

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestIterativeAndSynchronous()
    {
        var url = "https://localhost:44388/api/values";

        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }


    [Fact]
    public async Task TestAsyncWithParallelTasks()
    {
        var url = "https://localhost:44388/api/values";
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            });

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestParallelForEach()
    {
        var url = "https://localhost:44388/api/values";
        var n = new int[30];

        Parallel.ForEach(n, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, (i) =>
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        });
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestSynchronousWithParallelThreads()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var url = "https://localhost:44388/api/values";
        var threads = new List<Thread>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread( () =>
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            });

            thread.Start();
            threads.Add(thread);
        }

        foreach(var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }      
    }
}
```

So any idea what's causing this performance hit?

I would have expected `TestSynchronousWithParallelTasks()` to be faster than `TestIterativeAndSynchronous()` as you'd be starting more requests at once, even if it's IO bound. While the latter is waiting for each request before starting a new one. So it seems like it's related to the tasks somehow blocking each other?

Edit: Added a test case to use threads instead and it's quick like the rest.

Comment: Could you share the performance measurements for each of the four tests?

Comment: Could you please share the setup needed to run your code?

Comment: Does the alternative implementation of `List<Task<string>> tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(t => httpClient.GetStringAsync(url)).ToList(); await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` perform any faster? It's similar to `TestAsyncWithParallelTasks` but without forcing the initial synchronous part of making the request into its own thread. Also you should be using something like BenchmarkDotNet to measure performance.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm just running the test multiple times. But I added the test result and duration in the original post.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's using Xunit. There isn't any other setup code besides the referencing the XUnit packages and Task libraries. I can add as a tag.

Comment: `TestSynchronousWithParallelThreads`? I can't see this test in the code that you've posted.

Comment: @Llama it's quick as well. But is that equivalent?  There's no `GetStringAsync.Result` or `async`, so would it not be exiting the Task early?

Comment: `GetStringAsync` returns a `Task<string>`, so you end up with a `List<Task<string>>`. `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` waits for all of the tasks in `tasks` to complete. Unlike `.Result` it doesn't block the thread its running in until the result comes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias sorry that was a new test I just added to create new threads instead of tasks. It seems to be fine as well.

Comment: The results that you posted make absolutely no sense to me. Is it possible that the only slow test, the one that took 19.1 sec, is caused by the time needed to warm up the local service that responds to the requests?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias great thought! It's not the service as it's persistent in the background, but it is actually during the first test. Seems obvious to try that now.  However, if I turn on Fiddler everything is quick. So it's possibly due to some http client setup or connection warm up?  Thanks, so doesn't look like it's related to threading at all.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Actually, if I run the tests individually, the original problem is back. But regardless, it's probably still some setup issue and nothing to do with threading. So I'll consider this solved.

Comment: This is why you should use BenchmarkDotNet for measuring performance :)

Comment: @Llama noted. Sometimes you just have to learn through the hard way.

Comment: If you want to perform a load/performance test against your WebApi I would recommend a tool like [bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier). It is a tiny CLI tool with high customizability to mimic any kind of workload.